# Hibernate - Database Results and Computional Complexity

Tags: java, hibernate, complexity-theory

I'd like to ask a more theoretical question. I've written a method that takes one argument: a username. Then it retrieves all the rows from the table and adds them to the List collection.
After creating the List I'm iterating over it and checking whether the argument username matches the one from the collection. If so, I'm setting the boolean value to true.

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from User");
        List userList = query.list();
        Iterator it = userList.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            User user = (User) it.next();

            if (user.getUsername().equals(username)) {
                status = false;
                break;
            }
}
```

I'd like to ask about the computional complexity of this code in two cases.

As far as I know the computational complexity of searching a list is **O(n)**.

1. So I find the matching username, but don't break the loop, it will iterate over the all records, so the complexity will be **O(n)**
2. If I break the loop with the **break** statement when I find the matching username, the loop won't iterate further. If so, will the computational complexity fall down to **O(N-x)**
   where: x - the number of rows that have not been selected so far.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

[Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) is used in analyzing algorithms, and the point is to abstract away the irrelevant specifics and talk about an upper bound on growth in general, without reference to a particular problem size (there may be a minimum size below which the behavior doesn't hold, but it's mainly concerned with asymptotic behavior, because that's what's interesting).

If you break from the loop the upper bound on the function's growth is still O(N), the difference is only off by a constant factor, and constants are insignificant because we're describing the growth of the function as the input size gets arbitrarily large. So N - x is just N.